# SlowPrint with colors

Tags: python, colorama

I have an issue. I'm not able to use the slowprint function at the same time as colorama or other color modules.

Here's my code:

```
import os, sys
import time
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

#SlowPrint 
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)
#Test
print_slow (f"{Fore.RED}Hello World")
```

The output is:

`←[31mHellow World`

Instead of the actual color getting applied. How do I fix this?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't make your code sleep between the`colorama` control codes. Send them as a single string before the spaced-out stuff.

Comment: @BoarGules can you give an example of code? I'm a beginner so i didnt really understand what im supposed to do. thanks :)

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks for the reply, i thaught my problem was finally solved but when i tried that the output was just a plain "Hello World" without anything.
this was the code:
print(Fore.RED, end=""); print_slow ("Hello World")

Comment: This exchange of comments got out of hand so I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing `print_slow(f"{Fore.RED}Hello World")`. But what you are doing in `print_slow()` appears to be affecting the way your console driver handles the VT100 emulation that acts on the control codes for the colours. Understand that when you see `←[31m`, that is what is *actually being sent to the console*. The codes only make colours because of a decades-old convention introduced by [DEC dumb terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100). They only work with terminal drivers. Don't expect to see the colours in an IDE, or if you pipe the output to a file and open it in Notepad.

So, don't call `print_slow()` on the control codes. Instead, do `print(Fore.RED, end="")` and only after that `print_slow ("Hello World")`. But if you do that, you also have to change

```
colorama.init(autoreset=True)
```

to

```
colorama.init(autoreset=False)
```

because if you set `autoreset=True`, that unsets the colours after every call to `print()`. But if you change `autoreset`, you may also have to do `print(Style.RESET_ALL, end="")` to explicitly unset the colours. Whether you need that depends on what else your program is doing.

This will fix the problem:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=False)


def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Fore.RED, end="")
    print_slow("Hello World")
    print(Style.RESET_ALL, end="")
```